# Using pandas to read from .csv file but it's cutting off the decimal places?

Tags: python

I am trying to read in temperature data from a .csv file using pandas. Here is a sample of the file:

[image]

My issue is that my code is not extracting the data to 1 decimal place? This is what I have at the moment:

```
# Import packages
import pandas as pd

# Open  data file
data_file_name = "data_set.csv"
data_file = pd.read_csv(data_file_name, header=2).astype(int)

# Extract temperature data
target_data = data_file["Temperature"].astype(float)
print(target_data.loc[[0]])
```

After adding in the print statement to see if the first value is -23.5 as it should be, instead I get:

```
-23.0
```

Why isn't my code reading the data as a float with 1 d.p?

Comment: You are converting all values to integers with `astype(int)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your issue is that you're reading in the datafile as `.astype(int)`, which is converting everything in the CSV to an int, so you are unable to recover the decimal by doing `.astype(float)`. Try to not specify type on the inital `read_csv`, as Pandas can normally handle properly typing automatically.

Comment: Ah thank you! That was left over from trying to fix a previous problem!